# как понизить скорость загрузки изображений

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

у меня на страничке плиточное меню из картинок вида

```
<a href="Javascript:func('1')"><img src="01.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

они весят по 10 килобайт, но сервер иногда ругается ошибкой 503 и не все картинки подгружаются

я так понял что мне нужно что то вроде

[image: a busy cat]
но как это разделить?

Comment: что значит разделить? и разделить что?

Comment: Поищите в поисковике по словосочетанию "CSS-спрайты"